# Reset password for phpmyadmin

Tags: software-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu. 
I have installed phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 18.04. During installation it did not ask for php admin password. So I am not able in login into phpmyadmin (through localhost/phpmyadmin).
How can I set a password so that I could login into phpmyadin.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tries to search it on Google.

Comment: yes. I tried 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin'. But, still I am not able to login to phpmyadmin through localhost. It gives the following error: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'rajmohy'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: As per comment below the answer: **OP is going for reinstall.**

Answer (score 2):

Typically, it is the MySQL user/password that you use, there isn't a separate one for phpMyAdmin.  The access you receive in phpMyAdmin depends on the permissions the user has in MySQL.  If you log in with the MySQL root user/pass, it will give you full access.

Comment: same result friend. Even after using mysql root + password, not able to login. Error is:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: do you get the same error from the command line?

Comment: Do you run a local MySQL server, or are you trying to reach a remote server?

Comment: In command line also access denied in mysql for root. I use mysql  local server

Comment: Run `mysql_secure_installation` as root

Comment: I tried mysql_secure_installation now. Again access to root is denied. ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: thanks friend. I need to use mysql & php for project urgently. So I have just uninstalled mysql & phpmyadmin. Trying to go for reinstallation. sorry for the trouble to given you.